# CLGeocoder reverse geocoding fails with Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 -

Tags: ios7, xcode5, cllocation, clgeocoder

With a CLLocation object (content e.g. latitude = 48.196169, longitude = 11.620237), I try to get the current city and country like:

```Objective-C
if(!geocoder) {
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
}

if (geocoder.geocoding) [geocoder cancelGeocode];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:lo completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if(devMode) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
    }

    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
        // MY CODE - here placemarks is always (null)
    } else {
        if(devMode)
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
    }
}];
```

mostly, that works great. But in rarely cases, I just get the errors:

> PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000
>   "Ungültige URL" UserInfo=0x16f5ff30 {NSUnderlyingError=0x16f57810
>   "Ungültige URL", NSLocalizedDescription=Ungültige URL}
>
> Found placemarks: (null), error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2
>   "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)"

I've absolutely no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to find the address line, here you have to pass latitude and longitude as a parameter

```
- (void)findAddress:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude with:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude{
CLLocation *location =[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Finding address");
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@",placemarks[0]);
    }
}]; }
```

Here you have to import the following
`#import <CoreLocation/CLGeocoder.h>`