# How to get location details from latitude and longitude in googlemaps,?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios, geocode

> HI all i integrated google map in my applications, i am getting lat and long of current location and try to get place mark from those lat and long but i get strange error in my code when i used geocode.

```
 -(void)viewDidload
    {
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
[self GetMyLocation];

   GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:0    longitude:0 zoom:16];
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.frame  camera:camera];
_mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[_mapView setMapType:kGMSTypeNormal];
[self.firstview addSubview:_mapView];

 }


- (void) GetMyLocation{
_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  }





- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    }
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

{

```
NSLog(@"My location %@", [locations lastObject]);
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

[_mapView animateToLocation:currentLocation.coordinate];


CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locationManager.location
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");

                   if (error){
                       NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                       return;

                   }

                   if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)

                   {
                       //do something
                       CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                       NSString *addressTxt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@", 
                                               [topResult subThoroughfare],[topResult thoroughfare],
                                               [topResult locality], [topResult administrativeArea]];
                       NSLog(@"%@",addressTxt);
                   }
               }];




   }
```

> I get this error in my console area Error Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)"
>
> get this error in console

```
                2016-05-04 11:36:23.578 Juststart[2220:673181]     ClientParametersRequest   failed, 2 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 " The request timed out." UserInfo={           NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x1478c690 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102}}}
```

2016-05-04 11:36:32.653 Juststart[2220:673181] ClientParametersRequest failed, 7 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x145c8610 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102}}}
2016-05-04 11:36:48.671 Juststart[2220:673181] ClientParametersRequest failed, 6 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x14551c30 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102}}}
2016-05-04 11:37:05.707 Juststart[2220:673181] ClientParametersRequest failed, 5 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo= {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap,  _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4,  NSUnderlyingError=0x14586b90 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "   (null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102}}}
 2016-05-04 11:37:10.712 Juststart[2220:673181] ClientParametersRequest failed,  1  attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102,  NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap,  NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4,    NSUnderlyingError=0x15f2cf50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "     (null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102}}}
    2016-05-04 11:37:25.237 Juststart[2220:673395] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed     (-9806)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the error result as `You get this error in case Apple's Geocoder knows nothing about provided address or  geocoder is not able to find the location.`

for example

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[[CLGeocoder alloc] init] autorelease];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locationManager.location 
completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");

   if (error){
       NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);            
       return;

   }

   if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)

   {
       //do something   
       CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *addressTxt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@", 
                               [topResult subThoroughfare],[topResult thoroughfare],
                               [topResult locality], [topResult administrativeArea]];
       NSLog(@"%@",addressTxt);
   }
    }];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir

Comment: check this once bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376151/not-able-to-get-the-users-location-in-ios-8-using-cllocation-manager

Comment: Geocode is part of apple thats why i get this linker error?

Comment: sir i get this error in console  CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)

Comment: ClientParametersRequest failed, 7 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4

Comment: for your error see this bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9

Comment: still i get the above error and also get this Geocode failed with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)"

Comment: see this once bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512566/clgeocoder-reverse-geocoding-fails-with-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1000

Comment: Hello sir should i call this method from diupdate location - (void)findAddress:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude with:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude{

Comment: i am still stuck here sir

Comment: this is my plist for Apptransport <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <!--Connect to anything (this is probably BAD)-->
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>

Comment: see this once bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file

Comment: bro situation is stil same

Comment: yes sir problem is solved i need to update my plist as follows <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
       
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad add the following.

```
[_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```